# Call php page using script source

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a php page,say demo.php and i am calling this page using `<script src="demo.php"></script>`. I need to know whether it is possible to load another page using javascript.
I tried to include a javascript function ,but the required page is not loading.Please find me a solution.

Comment: I have a php page,say demo.php and i am calling this page using <script src="demp.php"></script>

Comment: Tell us a bit more about what the included page should do. I think you want to use ajax.

Comment: why you are calling server side page via client side coding ?

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you are confusing server side and client side... if you want demo.php always included, just include it when you build your site via a php include, if you need it dynamical, as a result of a user action, you need to make an ajax call to request it from the server. jQuery &co have easy to use ajax functions

Comment: I have never seen a way like this to load dynamic pages. LOL

Comment: Better, than ajax, because it is not restricted by the *same origin policy*

Comment: @IgorPatychenko I think loading Javascript file using javascript instead jquery/ajax is faster than simple "echo" using PHP.

Comment: @MarinSagovac definitely. But he is trying to load a php file via javascript source.

Comment: Do you actually understand which scripts are executed on your web server and which ones are sent unmodified to the browser and executed there?

Comment: I see some potential in using this.

Answer (score 2):

write method  and save. and in file like filename.js

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="filename.js"></script>
<head/>
```

or  use

```
<script type="text/php" src="demo.php"></script>
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div').load('demo.php');
});
```

you can also use ajax. like

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "demo.php",
        data: { name: name, email: email }
            ,
            success: function(msg) {
               // alert(msg);
            }
        });
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what he did.

Comment: It is very much interesting, how Client side code, like <script> loading such Serverside code like `demo.php` this opens a lot of potential.

Answer (score 0):

Skip this answer if you don't want like this, but this is using PHP as example. Someone need this example.

In PHP include using Javascript code:

`<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="somejavscript.js" />'`

Check is really your javascript code:

Or check it like this:

```
<head>
<?php 

$javascript_file = "somedir/somejavscript.js";

if (file_exists($javascript_file))
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$javascript_file.'" />' ?>
}
else
{
    die('file not found: '.$javascript_file);
}
?>
</head>
```

Note, if `die()` functions call it will stop script and show message error! Use it only for testing.

Comment: This is for redirection. I asked whether is it possible to load another php page using javascript if i am calling demo.php from script source.

Comment: please read the question! s/he is trying to call a serverside php script, not js!

Comment: I know what he is trying but he can try.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can just call

```
$.getScript('other_file.js', function() {
   // script loaded
});
```

without jQuery you can append script in head

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', 'other_file.js');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

**EDIT**: if that file is not javascript inside php then to call it just use normal ajax. Using jQuery it will be:

```
$.get('script.php', function(result) {
   // do something with output from a script
});
```

Comment: please read the question! s/he is trying to call a serverside php script, not js!

Answer (score 0):

According to comments, I'm not sure, what are you looking for. I assume, if you want to load another page, that means you want to load another HTML page, thus it is called redirect:

Try modifying the window.location property from javascript. `window.location.href = "demo.php";`

Or more precisely: `window.top.location.href = "demo.php";`

But if you want to dynamically load a script file, than you can use the jQuery load function as mentioned in the comments, or use 3 lines of javascript:

```
var s = document.createElement("script"); // create an empty script tag
s.src = "demp.php"; // specify source
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s); // append it to the head tag

// Optionally you can delete the new script tag from the DOM, because the executed code will remain in the memory:
s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
```

Hope this helps.

Also, if you want to call PHP functions from javascript( because I read that too in comments ), than look for the PHP library: [XAJAX](http://www.xajax-project.org/)

Comment: This is redirect, he needs load JS script.

Comment: The question is a bit ambigious to me, so I updated my answer, thanks for noting me.

Comment: "ambigious" > "ambigUous"

Comment: Sorry, mate, I'm hungarian, but I grew to love this word, since I first saw it in a MySQL error. But thanks for the info. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load another page in the current page, use [ajax with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (simple and cross-browser).

Create to javascript files (*.js):

- "jquery.min.js" and copy/ paste [this][2] in.
- "actions.js"

In actions.js :

```
jQuery(function($){

  $.ajax({
    url: "demo.php"     
  })
  .done(function(data){
    $("body").append(data) // add the loaded page as html at the body end
  })
  .fail(function(){
    console.log("fail to load demo.php");
  });

});
```